# Finding quantiles in Julia

Tags: julia, quantile

I need a function like `xtile` in Stata, that given a vector, it returns which quantile each obs belongs to. So if the function is defined as

```
function xtile(vector; q= 4) #q = 4 by default returns quartiles
    *** returns a vector with the same size as "vector", indicating which quantile each obs belongs to.
end
```

I want to use it in:

```
@pipe df |> transform(:height => xtile => :quantiles)
```

I know [Stella.jl](https://github.com/mwsohn/Stella.jl) provides such functionality. But I can't install that package and now I'm wondering if there is another package for it. Or maybe I can implement it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ready-made solution can be found with the [`cut` method](https://categoricalarrays.juliadata.org/stable/apiindex/#CategoricalArrays.cut-Tuple%7BAbstractArray,Integer%7D) provided by the [`CategoricalArrays.jl` package](https://categoricalarrays.juliadata.org/stable/), as long as you are okay with an `AbstractVector` of `Strings`:

```
using CategoricalArrays

x = rand(10);
cut(x, 4)
# 10-element CategoricalArray{String,1,UInt32}:
#  "Q4: [0.565838, 0.85564]"
#  "Q2: [0.333373, 0.393529)"
#  "Q4: [0.565838, 0.85564]"
#  "Q3: [0.393529, 0.565838)"
#  "Q1: [0.0381196, 0.333373)"
#  "Q3: [0.393529, 0.565838)"
#  "Q4: [0.565838, 0.85564]"
#  "Q1: [0.0381196, 0.333373)"
#  "Q1: [0.0381196, 0.333373)"
#  "Q2: [0.333373, 0.393529)"
```

If you want the quantiles as numbers, you can get the level codes by broadcasting [`levelcode`](https://categoricalarrays.juliadata.org/stable/apiindex/#CategoricalArrays.levelcode-Tuple%7BCategoricalValue%7D):

```
a = cut(x, 4);
levelcode.(a)
# 10-element Array{Int64,1}:
#  4
#  2
#  4
#  3
#  1
#  3
#  4
#  1
#  1
#  2
```

This can be easily converted to a function that works in a pipe:

```
xtile(x; n=4) = levelcode.(cut(x, n));
xtile(x)
# 10-element Array{Int64,1}:
#  4
#  2
#  4
#  3
#  1
#  3
#  4
#  1
#  1
#  2

xtile(x, n=5)
# 10-element Array{Int64,1}:
#  4
#  2
#  5
#  4
#  1
#  3
#  5
#  2
#  1
#  3
```

Answer (score 6):

While using the CategoricalArrays package is a good solution and has the added benefit of actually showing what the quantiles mean, it is very easy to implement `xtile` using just the Julia standard library:

```
using Statistics
function xtile(x; n=4)
    q = quantile(x, LinRange(0, 1, n + 1))
    map(v -> min(searchsortedlast(q, v), n), x)
end
```